# Enumerate all Map Markers

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Can anyone share some JavaScript that enumerates all markers in a Google Map?
Need script for v2 and v3 if possible.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only time you have access to the markers and can enumerate them is when they are created. The map has no awareness of what markers are attached to it, and it seems like you want to be able to do it on a map that has been initialised and markers have been added.

In other words, that is not possible. The way to do this is to put the markers into an array while you make them.

Comment: Thanks Kasper, that's what I thought.